i use Vuexy template that is build on vite vue3 and vuetify and i use pinia store, i want to add SSR to my project
the problem is that i get errors in localStorage and window being undefined in all my pages like themes, plugins and etc
and my project is considered as a middle-large sized one so i can't update my templates or convert my entire code in Nuxt or any other higher-level techniques.
this step i try it to add ssr:

npm i express

creating entry files in src folder:



entry-client.js

import { createApp } from './main'

const { app, router } = createApp()

router.isReady().then(() => {
  app.mount('#app', true)
})


entry-server.js

import { createApp } from './main'
import { renderToString } from '@vue/server-renderer'

export async function render(url, manifest) {
  const { app, router } = createApp()

  router.push(url)
  await router.isReady()

  const context = {}
  const html = await renderToString(app, context)

  return { html }
}


i also added server.js file in the main root

const express = require('express');
const { createServer: createViteServer } = require('vite');
const path = require('path');

async function createServer() {
  const app = express();

  const vite = await createViteServer({
    server: { middlewareMode: true },
  });

  app.use(vite.middlewares);

  app.use('*', async (req, res) => {
    const url = req.originalUrl;

    try {
      let template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(url, path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
      const { render } = await vite.ssrLoadModule('/src/entry-server.js');
      const { html, state } = await render(url);

      const initialState = JSON.stringify(state)

      const htmlResponse = template.replace('<!--ssr-outlet-->', html).replace(
        '</body>',
        `<script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${initialState}</script></body>`
      )

      res.status(200).set({ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }).end(htmlResponse);
    } catch (e) {
      vite.ssrFixStacktrace(e);
      console.error(e);
      res.status(500).end(e.message);
    }
  });

  app.listen(5173, () => {
    console.log('Server running at http://localhost:5173');
  });
}

createServer();



updating the router

import { setupLayouts } from "virtual:generated-layouts"
import { createRouter as _createRouter, createMemoryHistory, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import routes from "~pages"

const router = _createRouter({
  history: import.meta.env.SSR ? createMemoryHistory() : createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      redirect: _ => { return { name: "home", query: router.currentRoute.value.query }},
    },
    ...setupLayouts(routes),
  ],
})



export default router


updating main.js

import { createSSRApp } from "vue"
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import App from '@/App.vue'
import router from '@/router'
import { abilitiesPlugin } from '@casl/vue'
import ability from '@/plugins/casl/ability'
import i18n from '@/plugins/i18n'
import layoutsPlugin from '@/plugins/layouts'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'
import { loadFonts } from '@/plugins/webfontloader'
import '@/@iconify/icons-bundle'

import '@core/scss/template/index.scss'
import '@styles/styles.scss'
import { createHead } from '@unhead/vue'
import PerfectScrollbar from "vue3-perfect-scrollbar"
import "vue3-perfect-scrollbar/dist/vue3-perfect-scrollbar.css"
import { VueReCaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha-v3'

loadFonts()

export function createApp() {

  const app = createSSRApp(App)
  const head = createHead()
  const pinia = createPinia()

  app.use(PerfectScrollbar)
  app.use(vuetify)
  app.use(pinia)
  app.use(router)
  app.use(layoutsPlugin)
  app.use(i18n)
  app.use(VueReCaptcha, { siteKey: '6LdmJigpAAAAAL00fhfzR9sV4RgkQ5OvS8g5qKu4', loaderOptions: { useRecaptchaNet: true, autoHideBadge: true } })
  app.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability)
  app.use(head)

  return { app, router }
}



updating package.json scripts

  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server",
    "build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
    "build:noExternal": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server:noExternal",
    "build:client": "vite build --ssrManifest --outDir dist/client",
    "build:server": "vite build --ssr src/entry-server.js --outDir dist/server",
    "build:server:noExternal": "vite build --config vite.config.noexternal.js --ssr src/entry-server.js --outDir dist/server",
    "generate": "vite build --ssrManifest --outDir dist/static && npm run build:server && node prerender",
    "serve": "NODE_ENV=production node server",
    "debug": "node --inspect-brk server",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 5050",
    "lint": "eslint . -c .eslintrc.js --fix --ext .ts,.js,.vue,.tsx,.jsx",
    "build:icons": "node src/@iconify/build-icons.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run build:icons"
  },
  "type": "module",

lastly i updated my vite-config.js
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'
import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import Pages from 'vite-plugin-pages'
import Layouts from 'vite-plugin-vue-layouts'
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'
import Sitemap from 'vite-plugin-sitemap'



import DefineOptions from 'unplugin-vue-define-options/vite'

import { compression } from 'vite-plugin-compression2'

import { exampleMap } from './exampleMap'

const dynamicRoutes = exampleMap.map(name => `/${name}`)


export default defineConfig({

  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueJsx(),


    Sitemap({ 
      hostname: 'https:example.com',
      readable: true,
      dynamicRoutes,
      nuxtStyle: true,
      changefreq: 'daily',
      generateRobotsTxt: true,
      robots: [
        { userAgent: [ 'Googlebot', 'Bingbot', 'Googlebot-Image'], allow: '/*' },
        { userAgent: '*', disallow: '/' },
      ],
    }),

    vuetify({
      styles: {
        configFile: 'src/styles/variables/_vuetify.scss',
      },
    }),
    Pages({
      dirs: ['./src/pages'],

      onRoutesGenerated: routes => [
        ...routes,
      ],
    }),
    Layouts({
      layoutsDirs: './src/layouts/',
    }),
    Components({
      dirs: ['src/@core/components', 'src/views/demos', 'src/components'],
      dts: true,
    }),
    AutoImport({
      eslintrc: {
        enabled: true,
        filepath: './.eslintrc-auto-import.json',
      },
      imports: ['vue', 'vue-router', '@vueuse/core', '@vueuse/math', 'vue-i18n', 'pinia'],
      vueTemplate: true,
    }),
    VueI18nPlugin({
      runtimeOnly: false,
      compositionOnly: true,
      include: [
        fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/plugins/i18n/locales/**', import.meta.url)),
      ],
    }),
    DefineOptions(),

    compression({ algorithm: 'brotliCompress', include: /\.(css|js|json|svg|png|ico)(\?.*)?$/i }),
  ],

  define: { 'process.env': {} },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      '@themeConfig': fileURLToPath(new URL('./themeConfig.js', import.meta.url)),
      '@core': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/@core', import.meta.url)),
      '@layouts': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/@layouts', import.meta.url)),
      '@images': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/assets/images/', import.meta.url)),
      '@styles': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/styles/', import.meta.url)),
      '@configured-variables': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/styles/variables/_template.scss', import.meta.url)),
      '@validators': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/@core/utils/validators', import.meta.url)),
      'apexcharts': fileURLToPath(new URL('node_modules/apexcharts-clevision', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },

  build: {
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 5000,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: './index.html',
        ssr: './src/entry-server.js',
      },
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['vuetify'],
    entries: [
      './src/**/*.vue',
    ],
  },
})


